# Meteor wrapAsync not returning value on client

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, meteor

I am trying to use Meteor.wrapAsync to upload a file using Slingshot and then get the upload URL.  I've created the function, but image_url ends up being undefined when I run it.  The image does successfully upload though.

**Getting the image url**

```
var uploadSlingshotFileSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(uploadSlingshotFile);
image_url = uploadSlingshotFileSync(image_file);
console.log(image_url);
```

**Function**

```
uploadSlingshotFile = function(file, callback) {
  var uploader = new Slingshot.Upload("photoUploads");
  uploader.send(file, function (error, uploadURL) {
    callback(null, uploadURL);
  });
};
```

Is there anything I am missing with the syntax of wrapAsync?

Answer (score 1):

WrapAsync make functions synchronous-looking only on the server, since Fibers are not available on the client.

Comment: Oh ok.  Do you have any suggestions as to how I could do this?